# Normed space problem

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I am currently dealing with the following problem:

Imagine you have two points $x,y$ in a normed space $(X,||.||)$  and in a convex set $K \subset X$.

Now you know that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset K$. As $K$ is convex you also know that $\forall \lambda \in (0,1): t(\lambda):=\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y \in K$. 
So you look at one particular $t(\lambda')$ and now I want to show that for all $ w \in B_{\varepsilon \cdot \lambda'}(t(\lambda')): w \in K$.My idea was to construct a line, that starts at the point $y$ and ends somewhere in $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ such that $w$ is on this line. This would include ( since K is convex) that $w \in K$. Problem is, I do not how to construct this line explicitely. Of course, it cannot be just any line, but rather such a line that $w$ is a convex combination of one point in the ball and $y$.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: The idea is that the cone generated by $y$ and $B_\epsilon(x)$ is contained in $K$. But it should be $B_{\epsilon (1-\lambda')}(t(\lambda'))$ (try the extreme cases $\lambda'=0,1$). Maybe that's where your problem was.

Comment: yes, of course the extrem cases are correct and yes, in principle I want to show that the cone is contained, but I am not sure how to actually prove this.

Comment: No: what I mean is that what you are trying to prove is not correct. Check the extreme cases: it does not fit for $\lambda'=1$. My comment was meant to propose you a corrected version. And drawing a picture could help (again, that's a cone).

Comment: yes, you are right. i had to interchange x and y in the convex combination. thanks. do you have any idea how to actually prove this ( without using geometric intuition)?

Comment: The convexity says you have a continuous map $\kappa \colon [0,1]\times K\times K \to K;\; \kappa (\lambda,a,b) = \lambda\cdot a + (1-\lambda)\cdot B$. What's $\kappa ([0,1]\times B_{\varepsilon}(x)\times \{y\})$?

Comment: well, it is exactly the cone. why is it important that the map is continuous?

Comment: The continuity is important to have a very simple way of showing that the closure and the interior of a convex set are convex.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to prove that if $x,y\in K$ and $x$ is an interior point of $K$, then for every $\lambda \in (0,1)$ the point $t :=\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y $ is an interior point of $K$.

The map $f(z) = \lambda z + (1-\lambda) y $ is continuous, with continuous inverse 
$f^{-1}(z) = \lambda^{-1} z + (1-\lambda^{-1}) y$. By convexity, $f(z)\in K$ whenever $z\in K$.

Let $N$ be a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $K$. Then $f(N)$ is a neighborhood of $t $ contained in $K$. Done.

I avoided references to the norm above, so that the proof  works the same  for topological vector spaces.